# Export data into different sheets in an excel spreadsheet using Pentaho Kettle

Tags: spreadsheet, export-to-excel, pentaho, kettle

I want to export data from database tables into different sheets of an excel spreadsheet. For example, employee data from a database table into sheet1 of the spreadsheet, department data into sheet2 of the spreadsheet, and employee_department data (joing the first two tables) into sheet3 of the spreadsheet.

How can i achieve this in Pentaho Kettle? I noticed that the Excel Output in Kettle has a content tab where you can select a sheet, but this does not seem to work. I tried storing data from different tables into different excel files sharing the same name, but naming the sheet option different e.g employee data into companydata.xls and choosing sheet1, department data into companydata.xls and choosing sheet2, and employee_department into companydata.xls and choosing sheet3.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the "Excel Writer" step instead. This is a much more flexible step for writing to Excel files - and is ideal for situations like this.

http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/12/using-the-excel-writer-step/

Comment: Hi Codek. Thank you very much for the recommended link. It provided what i was looking for. The trick is using the "Excel Writer" as you recommended instead of the "Excel Output", and also making sure that data loaded into the sheets are done sequentially since Kettle transformations execute concurrently. The link you provided explains all this and it worked for me. Thanks.